# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el delimitador por defecto en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

El delimitador por defecto en MySQL es el punto y coma `;`. Es decir, ese es el carácter que se usa para dar por finalizado un comando.

El problema reside en que a veces quiero realizar comandos que usan este carácter.

¿Existe alguna manera de cambiar ese delimitador? Si es así, ¿cómo debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, se puede cambiar con:

```
DELIMITER (Caracteres)
```

---

**Por ejemplo:** Imaginemos que hacemos una consulta a tabla "articulos".

**Por defecto sería:**

```
SELECT * FROM articulos;
--                     ^
```

Ahora imaginemos que deseamos que la instrucción termine en `$$`. Pues antes de nada configuramos el delimitador:

```
DELIMITER $$
```

**Y a continuación nuestra consulta será así:**

```
SELECT * FROM articulos $$
--                      ^^
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/260)