# Que tengo mal en este script para la creación de un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql

estoy creando este procedimiento almacenado por medio de un script, pero me da un error me podrian indicar cual es el error.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`newportaladmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `ExecutablesToBeDeleted`(
in productid int,
in platformid int,
in deviceid int
)
BEGIN
select e.idExecutable, e.bundleName, e.status from mybd.executables e
inner join mybd.products_has_executables pxe on e.idExecutable=pxe.executableIdExecutable
inner join mybd.devices_has_executables dxe on dxe.executableIdExecutable=e.idExecutable
where pxe.productIdProduct =productid AND e.platformIdPlatform=platformid AND e.status='distribution'
and dxe.deviceIdDevice=deviceid
and e.idExecutable not in
(select p.executableIdExecutable
from mybd.products_has_executables p
where p.productIdProduct!=productid);
END
```

Comment: y el error es?????

Comment: El error literal dice esto: 0 4 22:08:02 END Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: Creo que te falta poner los ``DELIMITER $$`` antes del BEGIN luego en el END poner ``END $$`` y luego ``DELIMITER ;`` @AndredGarciaMartin

Comment: Presta atención a lo que te dice @JavierG.Raya en su comentario. Para entender por qué debes usar `DELIMITER` y cómo usarlo correctamente, [revisa este tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-delimiter/). Si el código sigue dando error, pulsa en [edit] para ver cómo ha quedado luego de poner `DELIMITER`.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo ya se lo he solucionado pero no estoy seguro hasta que lo pruebe :)

Answer (score 0):

Es importante usar los [delimiter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-cambiar-el-delimitador-por-defecto-en-mysql) correctamente.

***La solución :***

***1.*** Poner `DELIMITER $$` Antes del `BEGIN`.

***2.*** Donde pones `END` cámbialo por `END $$`, el `$$` se debe al `DELIMITER $$`.

***3.*** Volver a cambiar el delimitador por defecto con `DELIMITER ;` debajo del `END $$`

```
CREATE DEFINER=`newportaladmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `ExecutablesToBeDeleted`(in productid int, in platformid int, in deviceid int)
DELIMITER $$
BEGIN
select e.idExecutable, e.bundleName, e.status from mybd.executables e
inner join mybd.products_has_executables pxe on e.idExecutable=pxe.executableIdExecutable
inner join mybd.devices_has_executables dxe on dxe.executableIdExecutable=e.idExecutable
where pxe.productIdProduct =productid AND e.platformIdPlatform=platformid AND e.status='distribution'
and dxe.deviceIdDevice=deviceid
and e.idExecutable not in
(select p.executableIdExecutable
from mybd.products_has_executables p
where p.productIdProduct!=productid);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```